# Web API: can we use ASP.NET Web API for Windows Service Hosting?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, .net-remoting

we have planned to use ASP.NET Web API for Windows Service Hosting instead of .NET Remoting and WCF service host.

Is it possible to have all the features in Web API that we have in WCF Service Host?.

Can we pass multiple arguments and complex arguments like Byte [] easily ?

and Can we get response as Byte []?

if so, can anyone give some C# examples for these needs?

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Comment: Hi @Tim, Can we pass multiple arguments and complex arguments like Byte [] easily ? and also can we get response as Byte []?